# Can't verify my domain for Apple Pay implementation

Tags: applepay

I'm trying to complete the domain verification step in order to test Apple Pay on the web.
I've downloaded the file, located it in the required folder and checked that I'm able to reach it and see the contents. 
When I click ok/verify I receive:

> Verification failed for domain 
>   Unable to establish a secure connection to 'https://my.domain/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association'.

If I open the browser console I see:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 421 ()
>   https://developer.apple.com/services-account/QH65B2/account/ios/identifiers/verifyDomain?content-type=text/x-url-arguments&accept=application/json&requestId=0544f9b2-3cfd-43e3-yd86-fbfb1b3f6613&userLocale=en_US&teamId=AYTGDKG3D8

What could be the problem?

Comment: 421 would seem to suggest a server configuration issue on your side. Is your server presenting a valid HTTPS certificate and supports the cipher suites listed in the documentation?

Comment: Yes. Maybe the problem is the CSR file Apple requires on the same merchant configuration page?

Comment: Once you've been issued the merchant validation certificate all Apple do is perform an HTTP GET to the URL to verify the content is the same. The CSR shouldn't matter at that stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that my server didn't have SSL score that is high enough. I manged to verify my domain only after my score reached an A.

I used this site to check my SSL: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Comment: You also need to make sure your server's request to/from Apple are over TLS 1.2

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your domain is not redirecting from `domain.com` to `www.domain.com`. That was my issue.

Comment: Can you refer to any link mentioning this rule?