# Apple Pay Web Domain Verification Having Issues

Tags: applepay

I was following the steps for Domain Verification:
https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/dev1731126fb?sub=dev21822a6b0

I uploaded the file to my domain, and checked it's accessible securely:
https://can-la.com/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association.txt

However, when I do the verification on my Apple Developer account, I get the error:
Verification failed for domain
Unable to establish a secure connection to 'https://can-la.com/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association.txt'. Domain certificate is untrusted.

How come, and how can I solve this?

(Not sure if this is the same problem as [Can't verify my domain for Apple Pay implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39749610/cant-verify-my-domain-for-apple-pay-implementation).)

Comment: Is it possible that your SSL was the issue? See here: <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39749610/cant-verify-my-domain-for-apple-pay-implementation">https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39749610/cant-verify-my-domain-for-apple-pay-implementation</a>